# Donwgrade Android Plugin for Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hi i am working on a project that builds and compiles fine on android studio 1.2(beta) but when building and compiling the exact same project on android studio 1.4 it fails to build and compile.

i notice how the latest android studio uses android plugin  1.4. is there a way to downgrade and use android plugin 1.1 from within android studio 1.4 or do i need to downgrade android studio too?

When i first imported the project into the latest android studio, it complained that my plugin from within my build script had to be updated. I then updated it to 1.4 and it failed the build.

I then tried force downgrading it by manually setting it back to 1.1 as shown below and it failed with the original message from android studio saying i got to update the plugin!

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.+'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an older version of the plugin - you also have to use an older version of android-studio

Comment: I have not found that to be the case, although it generally follows that pattern. I've used several different plugins with different versions of Android Studio. Do you have a reference for a support matrix?